# 2 div position fixed not working (html , css)

Tags: html, css

I wanted to created two divs both with fixed position, however my div class fixed2 which is background-red when I try put to fixed position the top is like same as the fixed1. Is it possible to move the fixed2 after the height stated in fixed1?

output:

[image: output]

```css
.fixed1 {
  height: 80vh;
  background: blue;
}

.fixed2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 80vh;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fixed1" style="position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100vh; height: 100vh;">
  fixed 1
</div>

<div class="fixed2" style="position: fixed; width: 100vh; height: 100vh;">
  fixed 2
</div>
```

Comment: `position: fixed` will align an item to the viewport. As such, the 2nd div will be always out of viewport with a height of `100vh`. Note, that inline-style has the highest specificity weight and will always oevrrule your CSS!

Comment: sorry im kinda new, cause i need to make 2 div with both of them got fixed position. cause i need to make each of this div scrollable without affecting the other sections

Comment: Your inline styles and your CSS rules contradict each other - that doesn't really make sense. Apart from that, two full-screen fixed position elements with the same position settings will overlap each other. This will only make sense if the top one is at least partly transparent.

Comment: but then you need to distribute the height that both of them dont exceed 100vh togetehr. and there is no need for position:fixed at all.

Comment: then what will i gonna do? cause im quite new also. im trying. but it doesnt work, can u give me advice for it?

Comment: well it is still very unclear what you intend to. your description is very vague and broad. Add clarity, explain in details, maybe add a drawing of what you itnend to. Why should a scrollable element effect other elements?

Comment: i added a drawing, i explain there why i need 2 div fixed position

Comment: I can't make sense of what you want the outcome to be. If both the fixed divs have such large heights (in relation to the window height) then the bottom part of the second div will never be seen. Could you describe more what you want and say how tall you really want those fixed divs to be?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you asked.
But if you want to have the second div below the first one, then you need to set the top with the same height that your first div has.
Of course this is if you want to use position: fixed, otherwise there are different ways to do it (in this specific case, you don't even need to clarify the position, it will take the whole screen anyway)

```css
.fixed1 {
  background: blue;
}

.fixed2 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fixed1" style="position: fixed; top:0; width: 100vw; height: 50vh;">
  fixed 1
</div>

<div class="fixed2" style="position: fixed; top: 50vh; width: 100vw; height: 50vh;">
  fixed 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering based on your comments it would be easier to use `Flexbox`. You could hardcode the height, but if you only want to ahrdcode the height of the first div you can make use of flexbox to let the 2nd div span the remaining height (`flex-grow: 1`).

Last but not least just add an overflow rule to the elements such as `overflow-y: auto` which will not increase the height of an element but addign a scrollbar to scroll overflowing content:

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* resets the default margin */
  height: 100vh; /* letting the body span the entire viewport */
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fixed1,
.fixed2 { /* distribute the space equaly to both divs */
  overflow-y: auto; /* to get a scrollbar during overflow */
}

.fixed1 {
  height: 30%;
  background: blue;
}

.fixed2 {
  background: red;
  flex-grow: 1; /* lets the 2nd div fill the rest of the available screen */
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed1">
  fixed 1
</div>

<div class="fixed2">
  fixed 2
  <p>this<p>
  <p>is<p>
  <p>just<p>
  <p>a<p>
  <p>very<p>
  <p>long<p>
  <p>text<p>
  <p>for<p>
  <p>demo<p>
  <p>purpose<p>  
</div>
```